# what's the best practice drf serializer in foreign key relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two model class

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    sha256 = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="children")
    a = models.CharField()
    b = models.CharField()
```

I'll request following:

(I want to save the child class after finding the parent class corresponding to sha256)

```
{"sha256": "ABC....", "a": "test", "b": "test"}
```

how to override the validate and create function
and how to write view?

I think:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sha256 = vadliated_data.pop('sha256')
        parent = Parent.objects.filter(sha256=sha256).first()
        if not parent:
            raise serializer.ValidationError('....')

        return Child.objects.create(**validated_data, parent=parent)

    class Meta:
         model = Child
         fields = ('sha256', 'a', 'b')
```

but it's not working correctly...what is the best way to do it ?

and this is my view(function view)

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def test(request):
    serializer = ChildSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serialzier.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
    return Response('...')
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your code. Try fix them, and if code won't work after that, than we'll see

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> your_app -> models.py:

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('sha256', 'SHA256'),
    ('md5', 'MD5'),
)
class Parent(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='sha256', max_length=64
    )
```

> your_app -> serializers.py:

```
from your_app.models import TYPE_CHOICES

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='sha256')

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = (
            'type',
        )

class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = ParentSerializer(required=True)
    a = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    b = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        type = validated_data.pop('type')

        try:
            parent = Parent.objects.get(type=type)
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('...')

        return Child.objects.create(
            parent=parent,
            **validated_data
        )

    class Meta:
         model = Child
         fields = (
            'parent', 'a', 'b'
        )
```

Comment: I write view like this
serializer = ChildSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
serializer.save()
but I got error message Field name `sha256` is not valid for model

Comment: Ok, got it, can you expand your question with code from your viewsets please ?

Comment: Also try code from my answer one more time, there must be a "parent" in your fields, not "sha256"

Comment: I expanded question, and i tested it with 'parent' instead of 'sha256'
but i got bad request parent this field is required

Comment: You need to create serializer for Parent like above

Comment: It works good but, if i have fields 'md5', 'sha256' and want to make two options. {"sha256":"AAA", ....}, {"md5":"AAA", ...}, Should I make two Parent serializer? I think it is inefficeint...

Comment: Can't you just add and "md5" and keep it with "sha256" ? Or you need to keep them mutually exclusive ?

Comment: i want them mutually exlusive

Comment: Ok, got it, check my answer, you can keep than mutual by adding choice field to you models and serializers

Comment: So have you achieved success so far ?